# Intel 64 bits, strange RSP behavior: changes by 2 or 8, not always 0x8

Tags: assembly, hex, x86-64, callstack

I came accross a problem with debugging a 64 bit binary in Windows using IDA. Normally, after a **push** RSP value should be deducted by 8. But occasionally, from IDA I saw that RSP was only deducted by 2, and then 8 for the next Push.

The codes involved are

```
push rax
push rbx
push rsi
push rdi
```

I'm quite new to x64 environment, thus could anyone explain this behavior ?

Comment: It shouldn't be 2 unless the code is using a 16 bit push (which is not normal). Show the instruction and before-after.

Comment: downvted: doesn't include details (like actual text dump from a debugger with before/after values on a specific instruction).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably getting mixed up by hexadecimal.  Counting by 8 goes

```
0  8  10  18  20  28  30
```

Are you looking at that and thinking `10 - 8 == 2`?  Because it's `0x10 - 0x8 == 0x8`.

Comment: @Jester: Nope, all part of the package :)  I've occasionally caught myself making this mistake for a second or two, enough to remember it having happened.  It took me a couple minutes while typing a comment to think of this, though. :P